# Flutter FFmpeg moov atom not found whilst running ffmpeg command during recording

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Hi am currently trying to retrieve 3 second clips of an audio file whilst it is recording in flutter. I am using the recording module [flutter sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) and [flutter ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg).

I record the audio file with default codec (.aac). The file is saved to the cache `getTemporaryDirectory()`

I then copy the file using this flutter ffmpeg code

```
List<String> arguments = ["-ss", start.toString(), "-i", inPath, "-to", end.toString(), "-c", "copy", outPath];

await flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments);
```

> Start: start time (e.g. 0) and End: end time (e.g. 3)

It then returns this error

> FFmpeg exited with rc: 1 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x748964ea00] moov
> atom not found

Helpful information:

1. A moov atom is data about the file (e.g timescale,duration)
2. I know the inPath exists because I check that before executing ffmpeg command
3. The outPath is also format .aac
4. This ffmpeg function is being ran whilst the recording is still occurring
5. Example inPath uri looks like this /data/user/0/com.my.app/cache/output.aac
6. I have no problems when running on iOS, only on android

I would be grateful for help, I have spent many days trying to fix this problem. If you need anymore info please leave a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Codec is not guaranteed to be AAC/ADTS.
It will depend of the Android version of your device.

You can do several things to understand better :

- `ffprobe` on your file to see what has been recorded by Flutter Sound.
- Use a specific Codec instead of default : `aac/adts` is a good choice because it can be streamed (you want to process the audio data during the recording and not after closing the file)
- Verify that your file contains something and that the data are not still in internal buffers
- Record to a dart PCM stream instead of a file. Working with a file and use FFmpeg to seek into it is complicated and perhaps does not fill your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, much appreciated. I will get back to you after I try your suggestions out 

Comment: Hey @GILO! I know it's been a year but has any of these solutions worked out for you? I'm getting the same problem in a video file, tried to ffprobe but keep getting the same issue

Comment: Make sure your flutter supplied codec to flutter is the same as the extension you are using @TiagoSantos